# How to create a mat-table with nested properties as rows

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have data like this:

```
const parents = [
    {
        name: "Bob",
        children: [
            {
                name: "Mike"
            },
            {
                name: "Sarah"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Jim",
        children: [
            {
                name: "Eve"
            },
            {
                name: "Kenny"
            },
            {
                name: "Brook"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to create a table that displays the nested `children` as rows, and would like to use `mat-table` to match the styling of the rest of my app.

So it should look like this:

```
Child Name    |Parent Name
---------------------------
Mike          |Bob
---------------------------
Sarah         |Bob
---------------------------
Eve           |Jim
---------------------------
Kenny         |Jim
---------------------------
Brook         |Jim
---------------------------
```

I also want columns to include both child and parent names. Currently, I have:

```
<mat-table
  [dataSource]="parents"
>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="childName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Child Name</mat-header-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="parentName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Parent Name</mat-header-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="parents">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let parent" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
      <tr *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
        {{ child.name }}
      </tr>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['parents']"></tr>
</mat-table>
```

But I'm getting stuck on how to get the cells to line up with the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="parents">
  <!-- headers -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="parentName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Parent Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let parent">{{ parent.name }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="childName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Child Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let parent">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ child.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ parent.name }}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: I believe this would create a table where the rows are parents, but then in the Child Name column, it's a row of the child and then parent name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataSource based in your data received

```
  const data = parents.reduce((a: any, b: any) => {
    b.children.forEach((x: any) => {
      a.push({ child: x.name, parent: b.name });
    });
    return a;
  }, []);
```

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) loop over all the elements of the array, Each element is get in the variable "b", and "a" is the "acumulator", that can be an initial value (in this case an empty array)